# How to make each point on [input type="range"] slider match the position of the slider-thumb?

Tags: html, css, slider, range

Similar to [Range input thumb gets offset over time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52564224/12690650)

I have a slider range which will be used to select a point. Each point on the slider corresponds to the value of that point. Min and Max attributes are overwritten by jQuery.

```
<div class="range">
  <input id="form-range" type="range">

  <ul class="range-labels">
   <li class="range-label">0</li>
   <li class="range-label">1</li>
   <li class="range-label">2</li>
   <li class="range-label">3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The issue is that each label is not matching to the slider-thumb (or is ever so slightly offset). I have used jQuery to calculate the width of the slider, and grab each child `li` of the `.range-labels` class, and then set the width of each child to the parent divided by the number of children (in this scenario, `.range` is 100% width and the input, and ul are full width to the parent).

**Jquery**

```
let range_input = $('#form-range'); // Get input element
let range_input_parent = range_input.parent(); // Get input element parent
let range_labels = $('.range-labels').children('li'); // Get each li inside of ul for labels
let range_width = range_input.width(); // Get width of input element

function calculateWidth() {
  // Get width of input parent
  let range_width_parent = range_input_parent.width();

  // Calculate width percentage of each li based on Parent width
  range_input_width_percent = range_width / range_width_parent * 100;
}

function setMinMaxAttr() {
  // Create empty variable as min
  let min = 0;
  // Create max variable based on total number of li elements in range
  let max = $('.range-label').length;

  // Set input attributes max / min respectively
  range_input.attr('max', max);
  range_input.attr('min', min);
}

setMinMaxAttr();
calculateWidth();

// Set widths of li elements to percentage of parent width
function setElementWidth() {
  let el = range_input_width_percent / range_labels.length;
  // Set width as %
  $(range_labels).css("width", el + "%");
}

setElementWidth();
```

**CSS**

```
.range {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.range input {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  height: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.range input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: -8px 0 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #37adbf;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0 !important;
}

.range input::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #37adbf;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0 !important;
}

.range input::-ms-thumb {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #37adbf;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0 !important;
}

.range input::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #b2b2b2;
}

.range input::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #b2b2b2;
}

.range input::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #b2b2b2;
}

.range input:focus {
  background: none;
  outline: none;
}

.range input::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}

.range-labels {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.range-labels li {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  color: #b2b2b2;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**JS Fiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/nbinks1/jg4169om/

Comment: The answer to that other question makes the point that you have to take half of the slider button width into account - I don’t see you actually trying to do that here anywhere.

Comment: The slider *thumb is a psuedo element, which means I cannot target this through jQuery. Additionally the answer to the first question is based on the range not having a min/max - This one does, resulting in steps. TranslateX on the number container does not address the issue. If you have a suggestion on how this answer can actually be achieved with this scenario, I'd love to know!

Comment: If you add `outline:1px solid red;` to the LI element, then you can see that it sits quite perfect on the line for the middle one (that the numbers are not exactly on those borders, because they are inside the LI, is a different matter), but for the other ones, the offset grows. (Do you need these “labels” to be clickable later? If not, I’d rather go and position the numbers absolutely in the first place.)

Comment: I see what you mean! Later, this will become a dynamic range slider where each point will grow exponentially (e.g. 0, 30, 70, 200, 600, 1000 ... where for each slider the number of points will vary) so it would be more ideal that the labels are clickable which in turn would make the slider-thumb reflect whichever point has been clicked - but I'm unsure on how to achieve this.